# Checkbox con imágenes

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo desarrollo web. Lo que quiero hacer es poner 4 imágenes centradas formando un cuadrado (como el logo de Microsoft) y que cada una tenga un checkbox (como para seleccionar cual de ellas comprar) y no se me ocurre como hacerlo, tanto el html y el css. Acá dejo el código que tengo para que puedan visualizarlo.

```
<div>
<div>
<p>Remera Naturalia</p>
<img src="Imagenes/Remera.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Remera Naturalia" id="remera">
<p>$25</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>Buzo Naturalia</p>
<img src="Imagenes/Buzo.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Buzo Naturalia">
<p>$30</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Gorra Naturalia</p>
<img src="Imagenes/Gorra.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Gorra Naturalia">
<p>$9.99</p>
</div>
    <div>
        <p>Funda para móvil Naturalia</p>
<img src="Imagenes/Funda.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Funda para smartphone Naturalia">
<p>$15</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solo faltaría que lo acomodes en cuadrado:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

label::before {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked+label {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked+label::before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked+label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Remera Naturalia</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="Imagenes/Remera.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Remera Naturalia" id="remera"></label>
    
    <p>$25</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Buzo Naturalia</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
     <label for="cb2"><img src="Imagenes/Buzo.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Buzo Naturalia"></label>
    <p>$30</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Gorra Naturalia</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" />
    <label for="cb3"><img src="Imagenes/Gorra.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Gorra Naturalia"></label>
    <p>$9.99</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Funda para móvil Naturalia</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
    <label for="cb4"><img src="Imagenes/Funda.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Funda para smartphone Naturalia"></label>
    <p>$15</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias es tal cual como quería, aprendí un montón de cosas que no sabía como el estilo del check! Quedó fantástico. Lo único que me esta sucediendo es que no puedo cambiar el tamaño de las imagenes, cuando modifico el width y height cualquiera sea el valor que ponga el tamaño queda siempre igual. Quizá debo modificarlo desde otro lado.

Comment: oh perfecto, para el tamaño te recomiendo que lo controles desde css ya que adicionalmente puedes poner más propiedades, borra el width y el height de las imagenes y pones una clase como class="img-size" y luego en el css pones .img-size{width:100px !important; height:200px !important;} y desde ahí controlas el tamaño en pixeles de las imagenes

Comment: Genial te agradezco un monton!

Comment: De nada amigo ((: